# ajax value not displayed in the model window

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display to open pdf file in model window. But it is not working properly. code is given below

```
<td class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger 
    deleteUser" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" onclick="edit_book1(<?php echo 
         $row['markid'];?>)">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i></button>
</td>
```

AJAX code

```
function edit_book1(markid) {
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form1')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('/users/ajax_edit1')?>/" + markid,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);

                    $('[name="markid1"]').val(data.file_name);

                    $('#modal_form1').modal('show'); // 
                    show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
                    $('.modal- 
                            title ').text('
                            Upload Images '); // 
                            Set title to Bootstrap modal title
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR,
                            textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('Error get data from 
                                ajax ');
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Controller

```
public
function
ajax_edit1($markid) {
    $data = $this - > User_Model -
        >
        getRows($markid);
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

model

```
function getRows($markid = array()) {
    $this - > db - > select('*');
    $this - > db - > from('upload_ins');
    $this - > db - > where('certid', $markid);
    $query = $this - > db - > get();
    return $query - > row();
}
```

model window

```
<?php if(!empty($files)){ 
      foreach($files as $frow)
                             {
        print_r($frow);                              
     ?>
<embed src="<?php echo 
     base_url().'uploads/files/'.$frow 
         ['file_name']; ?>" type='application/pdf' frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px">
```

I check it in the console the value returned. But no display in the model window. how to solve this?

In the console window I got

```
{id: "0", regno: "01107402042", appno: "10001", certid: "1", file_name: "9bfe44de3ddb583778d2b641bdb6b79f.pdf", …}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your result output is a json object. If it is then you would need to convert it using json_decode() and then access the item.

```
$f_row = json_decode($frow, TRUE);
```

The TRUE parameter of the `json_decode()` function will return the data as an associative array, you can now access the row data by keys.

```
$f_row['file_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="markid1"]').val(data.file_name);
```

name = "markid1" is an input tag or div Or Span?

val method will work only with input tag.

If you are using div or span tag then you should use **text()** method instead of **val()** method.

Please use this.

Thanks

Comment: i am using <embed src

Comment: Ok, then you should use like that.
$('[name="markid1"]').attr('src',data.file_name);

It will work.

Comment: In ajax  $('[name="markid1"]').attr('src',data.file_name);

Comment: In model window <div class="modal-body">
                        <embed src = "<?php echo base_url().'uploads/files/'.$frow ['file_name']; ?>" name ="markid1" type='application/pdf' frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px">

Comment: you are making dynamic src using PHP or AJAX ?

Comment: If you are aware with github GIST, then please share your code here.

https://gist.github.com

Comment: i shared my coding. link also sent.

Comment: are u check it.

Comment: Can you please do inpect element ? for modal and then share embed tag HTML, want to cross check what HTML is there.

Comment: i changed my coding also . inspect element return a87356245767aa912a72e93b23735d1f.pdf